# rosserial for Mbed on ROS Groovy - [solved]

Tags: python, rosserial, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to get the Mbed working with rosserial, on ROS Groovy Ubunbu 12.04 x64.
The Mbed node works well on Electric + Ubuntu 10.04 x64.
I've installed rosserial using : sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-rosserial
So it ought to be a version that works on Groovy.

**EDIT** : I've just found out that the package ros-groovy-rosserial install an old version of rosserial (0.2.0 instead of 0.3.0), why ? That must explain the issue.

My Mbed client side is based on the one made by Nucho, that works well on ROS Electric : mbed.org/users/nucho/code/rosserial_mbed_lib/

So I've mixed it with the files of the new rosserial_arduino library (located in /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/rosserial/rosserial_arduino/libraries/ros_lib), and using the mbed MODSERIAL library from Andy Kirkham, revision 25:ae0408ebdd68.

My mbed code uses custom messages, that I've rebuild as well, so my mbed program compiles ok. It uses Publishers and Subscribers.

Now on the PC side, when I run the python script, both side are trying to connect, but I've got this error when they try to establish publishers ans subscribers :

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyUSB0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1359047617.162067] ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [WallTime: 1359047617.166324] Connected on /dev/ttyUSB0 at 115200 baud
[INFO] [WallTime: 1359047619.272324] Failed Packet Flags 
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1359047619.280724] Failed to parse subscriber. unpack requires a string argument of length 4
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1359047619.285447] Failed to parse subscriber. unpack requires a string argument of length 4
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1359047619.377166] Tried to publish before configured, topic id 125
```

I think the error occurs on line 219 and 227 of the script SerialClient.py :

```
m.deserialize(msg)
```

I think the error might come from the mbed side.
Does anyone have an idea on this unpack error, or have seen it on other hardware like the arduino ?

Except the library above I haven't found anything on ROS+Mbed, does anyone use rosserial on the mbed ?

Thanks for your answers.
Regards.

**EDIT : I've found the solution to this thread :**

1 - Don't install rosserial through apt-get, but instead go to your ROS workspace, install mercurial if need :

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial
```

2 - Then download the rosserial 0.3.0 package this way in your ROS workspace (replace the middle with the real link, unfortunately I can't post it yet, not enough karma ^^):

```
hg clone here_type_the_source_link_found_on_rossrerial_wiki rosserial
```

3 - And build it :

```
rospack profile
rosmake rosserial
```

4 - Use Nucho's mbed library as it is (keep the MODSERIAL included). For me everything works as on Electric.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53297/rosserial-for-mbed-on-ros-groovy---%5Bsolved%5D/) by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 157 on 2013-01-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) on 2013-03-31**:
Hey I am having the same issue as you had. Trying to install via "hg clone https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial.git rosserial" is returning an HTTP 406: Not Acceptable

Not sure why, and googling is not helping

**Comment by [P.Naughton](https://answers.ros.org/users/2954/p.naughton/) on 2013-04-11**:
you must replace "hg" with "git" to clone a git repository. hg was the command for the old repository location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

EDIT : I've found the solution to this thread :

1 - Don't install rosserial through apt-get, but instead go to your ROS workspace, install mercurial if need :

sudo apt-get install mercurial
2 - Then download the rosserial 0.3.0 package this way in your ROS workspace (replace the middle with the real link, unfortunately I can't post it yet, not enough karma ^^):

hg clone here_type_the_source_link_found_on_rossrerial_wiki rosserial
3 - And build it :

rospack profile
rosmake rosserial
4 - Use Nucho's mbed library as it is (keep the MODSERIAL included). For me everything works as on Electric.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0